# Throwing Summons with Strength Based Throwing Attacks with Homing?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e, player-techniques

Summon Constructs (Multiple Minions 4, Controlled, Horde) with Flight and Interpose + Strength Based Ranged Damage (Homing) was a funny idea a player of mine and I came up with a couple weeks ago so I wanted to ask: How far can a Summon move via Homing into a target, and can they by raw even be moved this way?

I kinda just say they move within 5 ft of the target which makes Interpose pretty nice on them. Flavor is also cool as floating weapons.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the Strength-based Damage attack is ranged, as per the text in Homing (bolding mine), "This modifier grants a **ranged effect** an additional opportunity to hit".

Homing does not cause the summons to move. It will just let their ranged attack attempt to hit again. If you are instead attempting a "fastball special" kind of attack, applying the Homing to your throwing attacks using Variable Descriptor (both scenarios covered with supplementary non-core rules in the *Power Profiles*), then you are in house-rule territory because the RAW don't really treat the ranged attacks as distinct objects. I personally probably would not allow Homing to apply to independently moving objects unless one of my players made a really good argument for it making sense and if so, the behavior would come down to collaborative storytelling rather than rules.

If you are instead trying to apply Homing to Summon, then you're even more into houseruling territory because there are no rules in the book for invoking Summon to miss, so you're essentially adding your own custom modifier to the power. It will work how the GM and you agree, with the GM having a greater say as the person running the asylum. Presumably, if they agree to this, they're used to dealing with oddball scenarios and they have an idea of how they want to handle it.

Comment: Seems even though the throw can move creatures and objects, Homing is unclear since it's a additional chance to hit, not necessarily another chance to throw... Throws as descriptor with effect seems to at least be a thing with Throwing Weapons giving them the Throwing Distance Rank (though then again not necessarily exempt from Ranged Attack debuffs from making high range attacks, you can at least make them trigger falling object damage if they're creates). Wonder if Homing is subject to the initial max range of the attack, or the range from the initial location of the target it tried to hit.